# How to use siunitx to align dollars amounts on commas?

Tags: siunitx

Below is my MWE. I would like to align a table on the commas. Having dollar signs in the table messes up my code (i.e. I can get commas to align without the dollar sign). Thank you for your help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits={3},input-ignore={,\$},input-decimal-markers= 
{.},group-separator={,}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lS}
Row1 & \$226,108 \\
Row2 & \$8,498,296 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=7,
         table-space-text-pre = \USD,
         table-align-text-pre = false,
         group-separator={,},
         input-decimal-markers={.}
         }
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\newrobustcmd\USD{\$}    % <---
\begin{tabular}{lS}
Row1 & \USD   226 108 \\ % <---
Row2 & \USD 8 498 296 \\ % <---
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]